# Jenkins run post-build step after post-build action

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, continuous-integration, war

I need jenkins to bounce a remote tomcat server after the war is deployed. We have the tomcat restart configured as a post-build step (shell command) and the war deploy configured as a post-build action.

Everything is working but we need jenkins to restart the tomcat server (run the shell script) after it deploys the war.

Is there a way to add a post-build step after a post-build action in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just have a second post-build action?

Comment: no because all post-build actions run after all post-build steps

Comment: Take a look at the Post Build Task Plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task). I'm able to do exactly what you're talking about with multiple post-build tasks.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, the post build task plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We do this by segregating our build and deployment jobs.  Our "Builds" do just that, they build and archive artifacts.  We have downstream jobs that pick up those artifacts for deployment/installation and will then restart any necessary services.

So in the deployment/installation job, the installation would be a build step, and the restart could be an additional build step, or a post-build action.

Comment: So you'd deploy using a build step instead of a build action? Separating the build and deployment jobs probably isn't a bad idea, but that still wouldn't solve the problem if we want to use the built in war deployment action - we'd still be unable to run scripts after that action.